# Signpost Oauth authentification on android application

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, signpost

I d like to use an Oauth authentification on my android application with a google account so that the user doesn't need to create a new login and password and that I don't have to handle the authentification but google does it in my place. I've been searching for a while but couldn't found informations on how to do this with a google account on an android app. Does anyone know about that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to use a special OAuth Library like *signpost*. Android has an [`AccountManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) with Google OAuth support built in.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5941354/1467115) for a minimalistic example on how to use it. Google's account type is `com.google`.

Google has also has a [step-by-step guide](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/oauth-and-tasks-on-android) on how to implement this using the `access_token` then to call the Google Tasks API.